# What is the behavior when clicking "Cancel" when there are multiple routes to an Edit page?

Tags: interaction-design, ux-field

We have a Hub page with a list of widgets in a table. There are 2 routes to get to the Edit Widget page:

**(A)** You can click the Edit button from the Hub Page and go to the Edit page  OR **(B)** Click the name of the Widget, which takes you to the View page where you can click Edit and go to the Edit page.

So, 2 ways to get to the Edit page...

**(A)** Hub Page > Edit Page
 
**(B)** Hub Page > View Page > Edit Page

My question is, for use case **(A)**, if you click Cancel on the Edit page, should we take the user to the View Page or the Hub Page? I would assume the Hub page since this is where they came from.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would always take the user back to where they have come from. One of the reasons is that they could be cancelling, and didn't mean to get into this page. You don't want to confuse them further by taking them somewhere else where they would have to find their way out.